# confuse about three forms of reference

Tags: c++

```
  T const&
  const T&
  T& const   //error
```

What's the difference of the above three? And if `&` is `*`,what will happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two forms are equivalent, although I would prefer the first one because it makes it easier to reason about template argument deduction and it clarifies *what* is being made constant (everything that precedes it): thus, `int const*` is preferable to `const int*`.

Also, there is no way of declaring a constant pointer with the prefix syntax (e.g., there is no equivalent of `int* const` where `const` appears at the beginning of the type). Therefore, for syntactic uniformity, I'd rather always use the postfix version.

The third form is an error when used in regular contexts, and it is equivalent to `T&` when deducing template parameters (references cannot be reassigned, so they're always constant in a sense and the `const` is regarded as redundant).

If you change `&` into `*`, then the first two forms are *still* identical, while the third one now declares a constant pointer to an object of type `T`. Notice, that this means that the pointer itself is constant (you cannot reassign it), not the object being pointed to.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;

int* const pA = &a;   // p cannot be reassigned, a can be modified
*pA = 42; // OK
 pA = &b; // ERROR

int const* pB = &b;   // p can be reassigned, b cannot be modified
*pB = 42; // ERROR
pB = &a; // OK

int const* const pC = &a; // p cannot be reassigned, a cannot be modified
*pC = 42; // ERROR
pC = &b; // ERROR

int& const d = a; // ERROR
```

Comment: The first one doesn't have "nicer interaction with templates".  They're exactly the same in every way.  Even if `T` is `char*`.  OTOH, it does behave nicer if `T` is a macro, but I have _never_ seen that.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Wanna bet? :-)

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's not what I meant of course. I've actually learned this from Alexandrescu's book. Let me come up with an example.

Comment: As mentioned in the book "C++ Templates",I found the first one is really easier to understand for me. Thank both of you!

Comment: @MooingDuck: OK, maybe not the best example, but consider [this code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1V8k5p$2) and [this code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1V8k5p$4) (comments are meant to make the point). They are two equivalent versions of the same program, just written with the position of `const` swapped. You should see how the second version makes it easier to reason about template argument deduction. It is simpler to see what `const` is being applied to.

Comment: Alright, when I said "exactly the same in every way", I obviously meant as far as C++ is concerned.  I hadn't been thinking about 
"ability for people to reason about code".  I guess that's a draw?

Comment: @MooingDuck: But that's what *I* meant :-) OK, maybe I should have been more clear. I will rephrase, thank you.